# Django template block gets printed twice

Tags: django, django-templates, block

I have this in my base.html template file:

```
<body class="{% block body_class %}{% endblock %}">
```

Then this in my view template file:

```
{% block body_class %}my_class{%%}
```

The outputted HTML looks like this:

```
<body class="my_class">my_class ...
```

Am I missing something?

**UPDATE**

### base.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
                
</head>
<body class="{% block body_class %}{% endblock %}">
{% block header %}{% endblock %}
        
{% block content %}{% endblock %}
        
{% block footer %}
        
{% endblock %}
</body>
</html>
```

### app/base.html

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
```

### app/view.html

```
{% extends 'app/base.html' %}

{% block content %}
{% block body_class %}login{% endblock %}
{% endblock %}
```

**SOLVED**

Figured out while typing the update. The problem was in using the `{% block body_class %}` inside `{% block content %}`

Comment: Could you show the full code that has the problem? As described the problem shouldn't occur.

Comment: My bad. I've put by mistake the {% block body_class %} inside {% block content %}.